# Can I set more than 4 memory access breakpoints in WinDbg?

Tags: debugging, memory, windbg, breakpoint

I can set a `DWORD` memory read/write access breakpoint in WinDbg with the following command:

```
ba r 4 0x0307F42C
```

But is there a way to set more than 4 of those?

Comment: `ba` is a processor breakpoint (hardware breakpoints). use `bp` instead. For more breakpoints in radare2, read [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/debuggingtoolbox/2008/05/01/special-commandusing-breakpoints-bp-bm-ba-bu/).

Comment: @Megabeets: I'm not sure if I'm using that `bp` correctly. Say, I have a DWORD in memory that I want to track. I call `bp 03DBF450`. I then do `bl` and receive `1 e 03dbf450     0001 (0001)  0:****` but then if I run the debuggee I get an exception from IDA pro: `779A2228: The instruction at 0x779A2228 referenced memory at 0x14. The memory could not be written -> 00000014 (exc.code c0000005, tid 5928)` and the debuggee crashes. This doesn't happen if I don't use `bp` command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are called hardware breakpoints and are related to [debug registers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_debug_register) in the CPU. There are usually 6 of them but only DR0-DR3 used to specify an address for hardware breakpoints.

Comment: OK. It makes sense. So what do I use instead to set the 5th breakpoint on memory access?

Comment: Nothing. You can have only 4 breakpoints on memory access.

Comment: Hmm. Thanks. Is it a limitation in WinDbg or is it pretty much how **all** debuggers operate?

Comment: I haven’t yet seen one that would allow to set more than 4.

Comment: @c00000fd: the limitation, to my knowledge, is a limitation of the ISA rather than the software.

Comment: @0xC0000022L: I'm sorry, ISA is what?

Comment: instruction set architecture    ( intel att x86 x64 itanium 32 bit 64 bit  mips sparc p4 p3 8086 80386  etc etc )

Answer (score 1):

Although windbg does not support *memory breakpoints*, memory breakpoints are another common approach to place breakpoints based on memory access instead of code execution.

Although most debuggers implement that internally, memory breakpoints work by setting the `PAGE_GUARD` bit for all pages in the memory breakpoint address range, and then filtering any exceptions caught for the specific ranges within the pages, and then resetting the page guard.

You can do something similar by placing a page guard yourself using windbg, however that's a lot of effort.

It is important to note that memory breakpoints are detectable with little effort and may dramatically slow execution (even further down than debugging), when debugging a piece of software with anti-debugging protection make sure you pay attention.